# Multiple Bitmaps in fixed area

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I am trying to build a card based game in which a card is added to player after every round. To win the match player has to remove all cards from his deck.However i have also drawn some additional button for some other purposes. The issue is that when the number of cards got high, they hide behind the buttons like below image.

[image]

Is there any way through which i can draw the bitmaps in a fixed area? Something like below image(Highlighted rectangle behind the card images).

[image]

Following is my code to draw Bitmaps for one player

```
private void setMainPlayer() {
    //    Log.d(TAG, "Inside Set Main Player Method");
    Card localcard = null;
    Bitmap localimage = null;
    int currentiteration = 0;
    int Card_Gap = Screen_Width / 10;
    int Down_Card_Gap = 0;
    int Down_Card_Gap_positive = 0;
    int Down_Card_Gap_negative = 0;
    playerList.get(0).sortBySuit();

    //  Log.d(TAG,"Main Player Deck size"+MainPlayer.Count());
    while (currentiteration < playerList.get(0).decksize()) {
        localcard = playerList.get(0).getCard(currentiteration);
        localcard.setCurrent_Y(Screen_Height - localcard.getImage(context, Card_Width, Card_Height).getHeight());
        playerList.get(0).setCurrentCard(localcard, currentiteration);
        currentiteration++;
        if (Down_Card_Gap >= 0) {
            Down_Card_Gap_positive = Down_Card_Gap;
            localcard.setCurrent_X(Screen_Center_X + Down_Card_Gap_positive);
            Down_Card_Gap += Card_Gap;
        } else {
            Down_Card_Gap_negative = Down_Card_Gap;
            localcard.setCurrent_X(Screen_Center_X + Down_Card_Gap_negative);
        }
        Down_Card_Gap *= -1;

    }


}

private void DrawMainPlayerDeck(Canvas canvas) {
    // Log.d(TAG, " Inside Draw Main Player Deck");
    Card localcard;
    int currentiteration = 0;
    while (currentiteration < playerList.get(0).decksize()) {
        localcard = playerList.get(0).getCard(currentiteration);
        canvas.drawBitmap(localcard.getImage(context, Card_Width, Card_Height), localcard.getCurrent_X(), localcard.getCurrent_Y(), null);
        currentiteration++;
    }



}
```

I am drawing bitmaps on surfaceview.

Any suggestion would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use card gap instead of  int Card_Gap = Screen_Width / 10; Card_GAP = (Screen_Width-MarginLeft - Button size in dp * density) / 10, if you wish to have dynamic placement of cards depending on cards you can set 10 to number of cards either

Comment: You could add the card into a `HorizontalScrollView` so all the cards can be accessed?

Comment: I do not know why you are trying to code without an engine maybe you are trying to learn or trying to do your assignment but one advice i can give is to use LibGDX for android 2d projects. It is way easier to do these things there.